# Sequelize find does not have success function

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following code:

```
app.get('/autocompleteEmployees', function(req, res){
    var term = req.param('term');
    model.Employee.findAll().success(function(employees){
        var responseData = [];
        for(var i=0; i<employees.length; i++){
            console.log('i: ' + i);
            model.Person.find(employees[i].personID).success(function(person){
                if((person.lastName + ', ' + person.firstName).toLower().indexOf(term.toLower()) > -1){
                    responseData.push({
                        label: person.lastName + ', ' + person.firstName,
                        value: employees[i].id
                    });
                }

                if(i + 1 == employees.length){
                    res.send(JSON.stringify(repsonseData));
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Once the GET /autocompleteEmployees route is called, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\lowerkey\Desktop\emasc\server\controllers\Employee.js:85
                                model.Person.find(employees[i].personID).success (function(person){
                                             ^ TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'success'
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\lowerkey\Desktop\emasc\server\contr ollers\Employee.js:85:46)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:67:17)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\lowerkey\Desktop\emasc\node_modules \sequelize\lib\query-interface.js:245:17)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:88:20)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\lowerkey\Desktop\emasc\node_modules \sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:78:10)
    at C:\Users\lowerkey\Desktop\emasc\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql \query.js:32:51
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lowerkey\Desktop\emasc\node_modules\sequelize \node_modules\mysql\lib\client.js:108:11)
    at Query.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at Query._handlePacket (C:\Users\lowerkey\Desktop\emasc\node_modules\sequeli ze\node_modules\mysql\lib\query.js:51:14)
    at Client._handlePacket (C:\Users\lowerkey\Desktop\emasc\node_modules\sequel ize\node_modules\mysql\lib\client.js:312:14)
```

What can I do to get rid of the error?

Comment: can you please add the model definition ? and also the line where you bind your models to the model variable?

Comment: to be honest, i never tried sequelize on windows :D

Comment: I figured it out: Turns out the employees[i].personID variable was null. Turns out that I'm dealing with asynchronous stuff, and by the time the code in the for-loop is called, i is already greater than employees.length . The solution was to have a separate counter that takes the asynchronicity into account. Sorry for the blurry description... it's been a couple days. Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: Unfortunately, not. :( Do you know how to iterate over items in an array? Both `i` and `j` end up 2 before the success function does its work.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that one does not simply mix for-loops with asynchronous code.

The solution, for those walking the same path as myself, goes something like this:

```
    Array.prototype.foreach = function( callback ) {
  for( var k=0; k<this .length; k++ ) {
    callback( k, this[ k ] );
  }
}

app.get('/autocompletePersonEmployees', function(req, res){
    console.log('/autocompleteEmployees');

    var term = req.param('term', null);
    if(term == null){
        model.Employee.findAll().success(function(employees){
            var responseData = [];
            employees.foreach(function(i, employee){
                console.log(i + ' ' + employee.toString());
                model.Person.find(employee.personID).success(function(person){
                    responseData.push({
                        label: person.lastName + ', ' + person.firstName,
                        value: employee.id
                    });

                    if(i+1 == employees.length){
                        res.send(JSON.stringify(responseData));
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easier to use the forEach call from the popular [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library rather than defining one yourself.